# Skip function is it's declared already

Tags: php, function, exists

First of all, I've used `function_exists` to check, if my function was previously declared but doesn't help.

This is my code:

```
if ( !function_exists('something') ) {
   function something($params) {
       [..]
   }
}
```

And when I enter to the page, which has declared this function twice, then the following error occurring: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare something() (previously declared in [..])`

So the question is, how I can check, if the function exists already, and if it exists skip loading it twice?

Comment: Just use **include_once** or **require_once** in your php code.

Comment: How have you come to have functions declared twice? If it is because of includes, you should be using `include_once()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if( !function_exists('something') ){
    require("something_definer.php");
}
```